# HTC Desire C performing poorly

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-desire

After using my HTC Desire C for a few days, it begins to show noticeable amounts of lag. For example, if I click on a menu, or open the dialer, or start to type message, it will take more than 6 seconds to open. Even when closing an app, it can take several seconds to complete.

How can I resolve this? Do I need to take it to a service center?

Comment: You could try a reboot, maybe something got stuck. Also, before giving it to the service center, they will ask you to perform a factory-reset to see if it's really the device or just some crazy app you've installed, or a "wrong configuration".

Comment: I've reboot many times. But still i didn't get.

Comment: Is there any option without factory-reset ?

Comment: Deleting all app cache might help. Either by walking all apps separately (via *Settings→Apps*), or using a cache cleaner app. Not sure whether that helps. Also worth a check: *Settings→Battery usage*; with some luck it's showing the culprit, so you could clear the cache of that app, or delete its data, or uninstall only that one app to see if that helps.

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM with an EXT SD partition? Your SD card may be starting to slow down / fail. They have a limited number of writes in them before they start to die. Have you sideloaded any apps not from the Market? They may be causing issues. You may well need to do a factory reset, don't forget to backup anything important!